# How to install the algorithms package?

Tags: installing, algorithms

According to my ubuntu 11.04 my texlive is the latest version. But when I tried to `\usepackage{algorithm}` it says file algorithm.sty is not found. I read the algorithm.pdf manual and tried latex algorithms.ins in terminal and again it says file not found. So what is the problem here? I installed texlive using `sudo apt-get install texlive` but it seems to be missing some packages that were suppose to be included. How do I fix this?

Comment: TeX will only search the local directory, or the TEXMF tree. Where did you "compile" `algorithm.ins`?

Comment: @Werner: Silly me I thought latex would fetch algorithm.ins from server or something like apt-get. I have just successfully run latex algorithms.ins. Do you know where I should put the sty files?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

[`sudo apt-get install texlive`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/texlive) does not install all packages from CTAN. [`sudo apt-get install texlive-full`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/texlive-full) does that (well, it installs everything that was on CTAN when the package was created).

If you do not want to install everything, you can just install [`texlive-science`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/texlive-science) which contains the various algorithm-related packages.

On Arch the equivalent meta package is [`texlive-most`](https://www.archlinux.org/groups/x86_64/texlive-most/).

Comment: How come it says tlmgr not found?

Comment: @Mark: That's the whole point: The Ubuntu/Debian packages do not include `tlmgr`. Only a direct install of Tex Live does that.

Comment: @Caramdir, Fedora/Red Hat has also split up texlive into a lot of packages, and (consistent with the philosophy of one tools for each job) they are handled as normal packages, i.e., no lexlive manager (`tlmgr` ;-) wanted.

Comment: If you wanted to figure out which package provides that file, you could use the command `apt-file find algorithm.sty`.  (Teach a man to fish...)

Answer (score 28):

As mentioned before, `texlive` doesn't install the entire TeX Live distribution. To install everything, you should use `texlive-full`, but it contains *many* packages that you will not even dream of using in the real life.

If you are using Debian/Ubuntu and want to use `algorithm` + `algorithmic`, then I would suggest that you simply install [texlive-science](http://packages.debian.org/texlive-science) and go on with life.

If on the other hand, you are feeling adventurous (not really), you may want to check the new version that I have been baking for some time on [github](https://github.com/rbrito/algorithms), but have still not uploaded to CTAN.

The new version features a slightly easier, streamlined installation procedure, with you having to worry about just one file, `algorithms.dtx`.

As the original question was about Debian/Ubuntu, I would like to point out a very valuable resource that many may not know, which is the [Debian/Ubuntu-specific information on TeX Live](http://people.debian.org/~preining/TeX/TeX-on-Debian/). There you will see directives on how to maintain your local packages from stepping onto the distributed versions of those packages, to ease the maintainance task, detailed in [Chapter 4](http://people.debian.org/~preining/TeX/TeX-on-Debian/ch4.html).

Answer (score 18):

For those who use `tlmgr` and were sent here because of modern search engine's tolerance for typos @drozzy's answer got me on the right path:

```
tlmgr install algorithms
```

did it. Trying this for `algorithm` or `algorithmic` individually didn't work.

Comment: This worked for me on MacOS Ventura 13.1 (with `sudo`)

Answer (score 5):

Compiling `algorithms.ins` in the local working folder (wherever you are currently working in) will produce `algorithm.sty` and `algorithmic.sty` that you can leave it there. This is the first place that TeX will search for style and class files. However, if you're interested in using these styles for other projects as well, then you have to put it in the TEXMF tree. I am not familiar with Ubuntu's tree structure, but I'm guessing it will be located in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011/tex/latex/
```

In the above location, make a folder `algorithms` and place `algorithm.sty` and `algorithmic.sty` in there, and run `texhash`.

Comment: Better put it into the local TEXMF tree (I believe `~/.texmf`) instead of the system-wide one. That way you don't interfere with the package manager. (Except of course if you want it to be available for several users — then you need to use a system-wide directory.)

Answer (score 3):

I follow these steps (I use vanilla TexLive from CTAN) --

**Step-1**: During compilation, you suppose to get this type of error message if a package/style file is missing -

> ! LaTeX Error: File `sublabel.sty' not found.
>
> Type X to quit or  to proceed,
>   or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
>
> Enter file name:_

**Step-2**: If `X.sty` is missing, search on google for it, like "X.sty + CTAN", you also supposed to get a link like below --

> www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/preprint/‎

**Step-3**: In CTAN, generally many stlye(.sty) files are packaged under some other folders. In this case, `sublabel.sty` is packaged under `preprint` (*Note the root folder `www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/Y`*). So, `X.sty` is packaged under `Y`. Or to make sure, you can go to the link to check if `X` is really in `Y`.

**Step-4**: Now install `Y`, use `tlmgr` (generally shipped with 'TexLive') --

> sudo ./tlmgr install Y

Everything related to `Y` (in this case `X`) will be installed.

Answer (score 2):

I faced one problem my `algorithms.sty` package was not being recognized even though it was installed. I went to folder it was installed and saw that folder name is algorithms but file name is `algorithm.sty` hence I changed that to `algorithms.sty` and now its working fine. Hope it helps some of you.

Comment: But you probably used `\usepackage{algorithms}` rather than `\usepackage{algorithm}`.

Comment: Admittedly it is confusing: There is the _bundle_ `algorithms` that consists of the _packages_ `algorithm` and `algorithmic`. The directory name is correct, it is named according to the bundle name. Also the file name was correct before your change. The package is loaded with `\usepackage{algorithm}`. Also the package file itself says: `\ProvidesPackage{algorithm}`. Using a different file name will trigger a LaTeX warning: `You have requested package algorithms, but the package provides algorithm`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because there is no `algorithms` package, only `algorithmic` and `algorithm` packages.

So you should do this instead:

```
% "algorithms" bundle
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
```

It is really confusing because the official doc calls "algorithms" a *bundle*:
http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf

but then goes on to say:

> This package provides two environments, algorithmic and algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Here's the command for OpenSUSE:

```
 zypper in texlive-algorithms
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `algorithms` install two packages: `algorithm` and `algorithmic`. Each of these two packages will have style files namely: `algorithm.sty` and `algorithmic.sty`. These files are located somewhere in your installation path, e.g.,: **C:....\miktex\tex\latex\algorithms**.
Import these packages using the following two statements:

```
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
```

Then at the beginning of your document try very simple statements such as

```
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE $S \leftarrow 0$
\end{algorithmic}
```

Then compile your TEX file and see, does it produce the algorithmic statements or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you need style file `algpseudocode.sty` then in Package Manager of MiKTeX search the file `algpseudocode.sty` by writing its name in the File name text field. The search result will show that the file is in the package `algorithmicx`. Then install the package `algorithmicx`.
`

Answer (score 0):

On Cygwin `algpseudocode.sty` is found in the package `texlive-collection-mathscience`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/541278/18790), on Ubuntu systems, you can just use the [Ubuntu Packages Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) for the file `algorithm.sty`. For *bionic* and *focal* it indicates that `texlive-science` should be installed, which is smaller than `texlive-full`.