# Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `ot2enc.def' not found

Tags: babel, font-encodings, ctan

I am looking for a solution. I know that packages can be downloaded from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/), but I never realized where to put the files to install them. I am using TeXmaker 5.0.2, but I don't know exactly where it looks for libraries and required files to run.

The exact prompt of the message goes as follows:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty >>>> 
Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `ot2enc.def' not found

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty >>>>
! Package babel Error: Unknown option `russian'. Either you misspelled it(babel) or the language definition file russian.ldf was not found.See the babel package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \ProcessOptions
```

Comment: it is part of the texlive `cyrillic` package so `tlmgr install cyrillic`  should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As David suggests, the answer may be using

```
tlmgr install cyrillic
```

But I was tired of installing packages from time to time, I used the full install of LaTeX. It is heavy (~4 GB) but it was worth it.

```
sudo apt install texlive-full
```

Answer (score 6):

A smaller installation than `textlive-full` would be just `texlive-lang-cyrillic`:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-cyrillic
```

In fact, you can find the package that contains the file `ot2enc.def` from the [Ubuntu search package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1912/396913). The [immediate query](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=ot2enc.def) for the file `ot2enc.def` indicates the package I mentioned.