# LaTeX Error: File `ctex.sty' not found

Tags: xetex, moderncv

When I use XeLaTeX to compile TeX in Ubuntu 22.04, it shows this error:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncvcolorblue.sty
Package: moderncvcolorblue 2021-12-16 v2.3.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter
 color scheme: blue
)

! LaTeX Error: File `ctex.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>

l.7 \usepackage
               [scale=0.75]{geometry}^^M
End of file on the terminal!
```

This is the tex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\setlength{\footskip}{149.60005pt}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}

\name{张}{强}
\title{Java开发}
\phone[mobile]{152344567}
\email{zhang@gmail.com}
\social[stackoverflow]{https://stackoverflow.com/users/26343868/john}
\social[github]{https://github.com/zhang}
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{教育经历}

\cventry{2009.09--2009.09}{本科}{XX大学}{}{}{}
\section{工作经历}

\cventry{2023.06--2023.06}{Java开发}{上海XX信息科技有限公司}{上海}{}{}
\end{document}
```

what should I do to fixed this issue?

Comment: If `ctex.sty` is not found, it is not installed. Depending on how you've installed TeX Live you either have to install it using `tlmgr` or the Linux package manager. With the linux package manage you need at least `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-chinese`, but I would recommend to use `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` to install *all* of TeX Live provides by Ubuntu.

Comment: Related (but with another package): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28627/277964

Comment: I Installed followed the official document https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally I run this command and fixed this issue:

```
sudo apt install latex-cjk-all
```

Comment: this answer does not match your comment under the question. https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html would install an upstream texlive not managed by apt. This updates the debian/ubuntu system texlive apt package. Your log `/usr/share/texlive/`  in the question does show you are using the system tex not texlive from tug.org

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is ubuntu:

`sudo apt install texlive-full`